# Incrementing an iterator to point to the next element of another iterator

Tags: c++, iterator

I have two `unordered_maps` and I wish to use two loops to iterate over their contents.  Traditionally, using normal for loops to iterate over a vector `vec`, I would have done it like below:

```
for(int i=0; i<vec.size(); i++)
    for(int j=i+1; j<vec.size(); j++)
```

The code with `unordered_maps` is as below:

```
unordered_map<int, int> m;
unordered_map<int, int>::iterator it1=m.begin();
unordered_map<int, int>::iterator it2=m.begin();

while(it1!=m.end()) {
    it2=it1+1;      //this is incorrect.
    while(it2!=m.end()) {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

How should I correctly initialize `it2` so that it points to the element next to the one that is currently being pointed to, by `it1`?

Thanks. `d(^_^)b`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unordered map [iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map#Iterators) are [forward iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator) and they do not support the `operator+`. Instead, use the [std::next](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) function:

```
it2 = std::next(it1);
```

Alternatively, utilize the [std::advance](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) function:

```
it2 = it1;
std::advance(it2, 1);
```

or a simple increment operator:

```
it2 = it1;
++it2;
```

Comment: Woah! I didn't know about that.  Thanks!

Comment: Since you're not using the pre-incremented value, it is usually better to use `++it2` to increment the iterator to avoid making an unnecessary copy that gets thrown away.  (Although it is possible an optimizer would get rid of the copy.)

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Indeed. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Hi @Ron, I have the same problem with the 1 GFG Coding question.  I tried all 3 (i.e next, advance, ++itr) but compilation error coming like

`prog.cpp: In member function int Solution::findLongestConseqSubseq(int*, int):
prog.cpp:40:18: error: no matching function for call to next(std::pair<const int, int>&, int)
         next(y, 1);`

Comment: @Ron, link of question
[link](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/longest-consecutive-subsequence2449/1)

**My Solution**
`unordered_map<int,int> m;
    int maxCounter = 0, counter=0; 
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        m[arr[i]]=1;
        
    }
    
    for(auto x: m){
        auto y = x;
        next(y, 1);
        
        if(x.second == 1 and y.second == 1){
            counter++;
            maxCounter = max(maxCounter,counter);
        }else{
            counter=0;
        }
    }
    
    return maxCounter;`

Answer (score 1):

Another option is:

```
while (it1 != std::end(m)) {
    it2 = it1;

    while(++it2 != std::end(m)) {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Got you.  Thanks for your input.